# How to use itertools for product using specific index value?

Tags: python, list, product, indexof, python-itertools

Below code outputs:

```
import itertools as it
list(it.product(['A', 'T'], ['T', 'G']))
Out[230]: [('A', 'T'), ('A', 'G'), ('T', 'T'), ('T', 'G')]
```

But, if the list is:

```
['A', '/', 'T'], ['T', '/', 'G']
['C', '|', 'T'], ['A', '|', 'C']
```

I want

```
[('A', 'T'), ('A', 'G'), ('T', 'T'), ('T', 'G')]
[('C', 'A'), ('T', 'C')]
```

which means:

```
list(it.product(['A', '/', 'T'], ['T', '/', 'G'])) if '/' in the list
else list(it.product(['A', '/', 'T'], ['T', '/', 'G'])) if '|' in the list
```

How, can I get the same result without removing `/` and `|` because this is a condition.

I think using index might work and tried something like:

```
list(it.product(['A', '/', 'T'], ['T', '/', 'G']).index([0,2))
```

and several other process but didn't help.

This code is a tail of a big code so I am not trying to build any function or remove `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply a `filter`:

```
>>> from itertools import product

>>> list(filter(lambda x: '/' not in x, product(['A', '/', 'T'], ['T', '/', 'G'])))
[('A', 'T'), ('A', 'G'), ('T', 'T'), ('T', 'G')]
```

or exclude them beforehand (this time I use the equivalent to the `filter`: a conditional comprehension):

```
a = ['A', '/', 'T']
b = ['T', '/', 'G']

list(product([item for item in a if item != '/'],
             [item for item in b if item != '/']))
```

---

Note that you can also do filters with indices when you combine it with `enumerate`:

```
list(product([item for idx, item in enumerate(a) if idx != 1],
             [item for idx, item in enumerate(b) if idx != 1]))
```

or if you have simple conditions to the indices then slicing the list is also an option:

```
>>> list(product(a[:2], b[:2]))
[('A', 'T'), ('A', '/'), ('/', 'T'), ('/', '/')]
```

Comment: I updated the condition a little bit. Can you please look at the problem again.

Comment: Could you clarify what the conditions actually are? I had the impression I understood what you meant - but given your new example (`['C', '|', 'T'], ['A', '|', 'C']`): what are the rules there?

Comment: if there is `|` in the list only create product of the values in the same index level. **ie.** `0 with 0 and 2 with 2 - which gives me ['C', 'A'], ['T', 'C']`

Comment: You mean like: `[items for items in zip(['A', '|', 'T'], ['T', '|', 'G']) if '|' not in items]`?

Comment: yes. I am trying to append the first method into the code but having some issue.

Comment: adding this code to my code is giving me error. This is what I did: `applymap(lambda c: '/' not in x, ','.join('g'.join(t) for t in it.product(*c)))` What is the problem with this code. I also added `list(filter(lamba c:....` but its not working.

Comment: What is `applymap`?  A pandas dataframe method?

Comment: @everestial007 Could you maybe another question then? This is definetly not related to your original question here anymore and this iterative approach invalidates my answer (for example your last edit already did that partly). Also I have the feeling this is going to be an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Its a function from `pandas Dataframe` http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html I think your code be be iterable with this code.

Comment: I understand that your answer it totally valid in the context. I wanted to put a small problem rather which I thought I could merge. This is the full code that I have: `d2_mm = (d2_list+d2_list.shift(1)).dropna(how='all').\
    applymap(lambda c: ','.join('g'.join(t) for t in it.product(*c)))` and, I want to iterate your code in it to achieve something. The original problem is in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030190/how-to-read-two-lines-in-a-data-from-same-column-to-create-combination-of-values I changed `c.split('/')])` to `list(c)` to keep the condition `/` and `|`

Comment: but that's a totally different question now! `applymap` isn't equivalent to pythons filter, so it's not even related to the answer. Could you please open another question? Just one guess `.applymap(lambda c: ','.join('g'.join(t) for t in it.product(*c) if '/' not in t)))`

Comment: you have my thumbs up !

Comment: NOw, I am having trouble inserting that another condition (for `|`). Hope I can do it by tomorrow? any suggestions from you?

Comment: `.applymap(lambda c: ','.join('g'.join(t) for t in it.product(*c) if '/' not in t) if '/' in c else ','.join('g'.join(t) for t in zip(*c)))`? And another suggestion: Please open a new question. You can definetly link to this and the other question there but you likely get better answers if you ask only one question per question.

Comment: @MSeifert: I actually put the big question question in parts 4 times. I think people were not interested in reading long questions. So, I resorted to putting it in parts - solving the ones I could and parsing the other parts based on answers on here. I am biologist and don't have any support around me, but stackoverflow has been a very good resource. I can give the link to the big question if you are interested. It's really complicated though. Let me know and I can poke you whenever I have issues. I understand I need to work hard on it and I am trying my best. thanks much.

Comment: @MSeifert: putting the code for additional condition didnt' give any error. But, the second condition dominated over the 1st one.

Comment: @everestial007 It's okay to ask several small questions, but please open another question. :)

Comment: Ok, I will do. Will update you with comment on this question.

Comment: @MSeifert: If you have time can you please look into this another problem for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102630/how-to-merge-two-complex-conditional-statement-defined-inside-lambda-into-one?noredirect=1#comment71377162_42102630